# Meaning of FETCH_CURSOR jconnect_implicit_1 in Sybase

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase-15.7

## Situation

I am trying to troubleshoot performance when connecting to Sybase ASE Version 15.7 from Sqoop over JDBC.

Though I cannot check things myself it appears to be 10x slower to extract data this way then with another tool (which uses ODBC).

## Observation

The DB team has observed the following:

[image]

## Question:

#### What is the meaning of `FETCH_SIZE jconnect_implicit_1:`?

Of course other hints on what may be causing the performance issue are welcome as well.

---

The DB team believes it means a cursor is made for each row, perhaps because of [this link which contains something vaguely similar](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0605/html/prjdbc/prjdbc14.htm), but I suspect it means something else as I have not found any reference of Oozie causing this over JDBC (we enforce a larger fetch size in the oozie command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Even* if fetch size is set to 1, it doesn't mean a cursor will be created for each row; it simply means the driver will request rows of an open cursor be sent to the client one by one instead of in batches. Still inefficient, but not *that* inefficient. However, there's no indication there that fetch size is set to 1; `jconnect_implicit_1:` seems to be simply an automatically generated name of a  bind variable. I believe Sqoop fetch size can be controlled with the `--fetch-size` command line argument.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Any thoughts on why this JDBC approach seems to be 10x slower than an alternate ODBC approach?

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information in your question to make even a wildest guess. Most likely, you either measure performance inconsistently, or compare apples to oranges.